# Isomorphism of group actions

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $X$, and let $H$ be a group acting on a set $Y$. I'm wondering if there is standard terminology or notation to express the following condition: there exist an isomorphism $\varphi:G\rightarrow H$ and a bijection $\sigma:X\rightarrow Y$ such that $$\sigma(gx)=\varphi(g)\sigma(x)$$
for all $g\in G$ and all $x\in X$. Basically, I want to say that not only are $G$ and $H$ isomorphic as abstract groups, but that they act in the same way on the corresponding sets.

Comment: Such a map $\sigma$ is sometimes called a $\varphi$-equivariant isomorphism even when $\varphi$ is not an isomorphism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be a left $G$-set and a left $H$-set, respectively.  Then, a *homomorphism of group actions* is a pair $(\varphi,\sigma)$, with $\varphi:G\to H$ being a group homomorphism and $\sigma:X\to Y$ being a function compatible with the group actions in the sense that $$\sigma(g\cdot x)=\varphi(g)\cdot\sigma(x)$$ for all $g\in G$ and $x\in X$.  See for example Definition 2.1 on Page 115 of *[Groups and Computation II](https://books.google.de/books/about/Groups_and_Computation_II.html?id=lyL8Ui36FKsC&redir_esc=y)* by L. Finkelstein and W. M. Kantor.  What you have is just an isomorphism of group actions.

If $G=H$ and $\varphi=\text{id}_G$, then $\sigma:X\to Y$ satisfying $$\sigma(g\cdot x)=g\cdot \sigma(x)$$ for all $g\in G$ and $x\in X$ is usually called a *homomorphism of (left) $G$-sets*.  In other words, if $\sigma:X\to Y$ is a $G$-set homomorphism, then $\left(\text{id}_G,\sigma\right)$ is an example of a homomorphism of group actions from $(G,X)$ to $(G,Y)$.

Comment: I do wonder if we have a homomorphism $(\varphi,\sigma)$ from $(G,X)$ to $(G,Y)$, where $G$ is a group homomorphism from $G$ to $G$, then is it possible to get a homomorphism  $(id_G,\sigma^\prime)$ from $(G,X)$ to $(G,Y)$?

Answer (score 5):

An action of $G$ on $X$ is given by a group homomorphism $G \to Sym(X)$.

Therefore, the action of $G$ on $X$ is isomorphic to the action of $H$ on $Y$ exactly when the diagram below commutes:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
G & \to & Sym(X) \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
H & \to & Sym(Y)
\end{array}$$
The horizontal arrows are induced by the actions, the vertical arrow on the left is $\varphi$, and the vertical arrow on the right is induced by $\sigma$.

The diagram can be used to define morphisms of group actions, not just isomorphisms.

Comment: What does it mean for a diagram to commute?

Comment: @samerivertwice, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_diagram