# What is meant by group action are isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, notation, terminology, group-actions

Let $\pi_1 : G \times S \mapsto S$ is one group action and $\pi_2 : G^{'} \times S \mapsto S$ is another group action. What is it mean by the statement that $\pi_1 \cong \pi_2$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331833/isomorphism-of-group-actions

Answer (score 1):

It means that there is a bijection $f\colon S\to S$ which is also a morphism of $G$-sets, a $G$-equivariant map, i.e. that $f(gs) = gf(s)$ for all $s\in S,g\in G.$

Comment: For the intuition for where this definition comes from, remember that all isomorphisms are statements that two objects are secretly the same, just described differently. The isomorphism between them is the map, $f$, that relabeled one object to give another. The left hand says that the relabeling the combination of elements according to the mapping that is preserved equals the mapping of the relabeling of the object.