# On the group action $\psi: X \times \Bbb R^*_+ \to X$

Tags: group-theory, terminology, definition, group-actions, applications

Today I revisited the concept of a group action with someone. I recalled the definition of a "flow" which is a group action of the additive group of real numbers on the set $X:$

$$\varphi: X \times \Bbb R \to X$$

such that:

$\varphi(x,0)=x$

$\varphi(\varphi(x,t)),s)=\varphi(x,s+t).$

I wondered about changing $\Bbb R$ to the multiplicative group of real numbers like so:

$$\psi: X \times \Bbb R^*_+ \to X$$

satisfying the conditions:

$\psi(x,1)=x$

$\psi(\psi(x,e^t)),e^s)=\psi(x,e^{s+t}).$

> Does the $\psi$ group action have a name?

Since $(\Bbb R,+)$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb R_{\gt0},\times)$ by exponentiation, I think these two group actions must be nearly the same.

Comment: I can see what you're getting at, but unless we have more information, I don't think we can say anything about these group actions. Explicitly, all you have done stated the definition of a group action on $(\mathbb R, +)$ and $(\mathbb R_{> 0}, \cdot).$ But it is correct that these groups are isomorphic via $\operatorname{exp} : a \mapsto e^a.$ If we knew moreover that $\varphi(x, a) = \psi(x, e^a),$ then we could say that $(\operatorname{exp}, \operatorname{id}_X)$ is an [isomorphism of group actions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2331844/390180).

Comment: If as you had originally written we have that $\varphi = \psi,$ then $(\operatorname{exp}, \operatorname{id}_X)$ is an isomorphism of groups, as you can verify from the definition.

Comment: @DylanC.Beck A group action on $(\mathbb R, +)$ is called a flow. I was wondering if there's a name for a group action on $(\mathbb R_{> 0}, \cdot).$

Comment: In your last line, you state, "I think these two group actions must be nearly the same." I was answering that question. I have not heard the term "flow" before in this context, so I am not familiar with any names for a group action of the multiplicative group $\mathbb R_{> 0 }.$

Comment: $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^*_{+},\cdot)$ are not only group isomorphic, but also isomorphic as topological groups. And therefore if one of those acts on a set/topological space then so does the other in an equivalent way. There's literally no difference between these groups, except for different naming (e.g. $0$ vs $1$). Both are models for the same topological group. So if you call an action of one of them on $X$ a "flow" then you can call an action of the other on $X$ a "flow" as well.