# Construction of certain kinds of maps

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ and $G'$ be two groups and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Take a map $f:G\rightarrow G'$ such that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x\in G$ and $y\in H$. By definition, the map $f$ is not necessarily a homomorphism. So, is there a name for these kinds of maps?.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the (right) action of $H \le G$ on the set $G$ by multiplication on the right, so that $G$ is an $H$-set. Consider the action of $H' = f(H) \le G'$ on the set $G'$ by multiplication on the right, so that $G'$ is an $H'$-set.

Then your situation can be described as a homomorphism of group actions, see for instance the first paragraph of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2331844/58401).

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a similar definition if $H$ is just a subset of $G$?